# why is read-only sqlce is very slow on windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

i am developing an app on windows phone 7 (wp7) using sdk 7.1. i am using the natively supported sqlce database. the database only stores 1 table with 5 "string" columns. however, there are nearly 90,000 records. the table is indexed (specified using the Index attribute). this reference database is always accessed from the installation folder (not from iso store, because it is read-only). i am using linq, per the recommendations on MSDN, to query for data. my linq queries are very simple.

```
var items = from e in myDataContext.MyItems where e.col1 == 'literal' select e;
```

in some cases, i have to implement paging, so i do something like the following.

```
var items = (from e in myDataContext.MyItems where e.col1 == 'literal' select e).Skip(offset).Take(maxResults);
```

the problem is that performance is very slow. i haven't tracked down where the bottleneck is, but i suspect it's with sqlce and/or linq. anyone have any suggestion for me on how to troubleshoot this problem?